# jooq getValue(String fieldName) Columns with the same name in different tables

Tags: java, sql, jooq

SQL:

```sql
SELECT tblA.hostname, tblB.hostname FROM tblA, tblB ...
```

When trying to get the hostname from each table, it does not work. For example,

```java
String clientHostname = (String) result.getValue("tblA.hostname"); 
String serverHostname = (String) result.getValue("tblB.hostname");
```

> Execution exception: [IllegalArgumentException: Field (tblA.hostname) is not contained in Row (hostname, hostname)]

Then, another attempt to correct the issue with:

```java
String clientHostname = (String) result.getValue("hostname"); 
String serverHostname = (String) result.getValue("hostname");
```

This does not return the desired behavior where clientHostname = tblA.hostname and serverHostname = tblB.hostname, it just returns tblA.hostname for both.

How do I get the values for both columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

"SELECT tblA.hostname **AS tblAhostname**, tblB.hostname **AS tblBhostname** FROM tblA, tblB ..."

`String clientHostname = (String) result.getValue("tblAhostname"); 
 String serverHostname = (String) result.getValue("tblBhostname");`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [explicitly renaming columns as Erik suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32761936/521799), you can access qualified column names like this:

```
String clientHostname = result.getValue(field(name("tblA", "hostname"), String.class)); 
String serverHostname = result.getValue(field(name("tblB", "hostname"), String.class));
```

This solution makes use of:

- [`DSL.field(Name, Class)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Name-java.lang.Class-) to construct a "plain SQL" field
- [`DSL.name(String...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#name-java.lang.String...-) to construct an identifier

More information about this API can be found in the manual:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql

Note, there's also a pending [feature request #4578](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4578) to allow for using the API the way you have intended.